# Is it possible to use ES6 For..Of on an Object instead of an Array?

Tags: ecmascript-6

On **babel-node** REPL I get

> TypeError: undefined is not a function

when trying to iterate using a For..Of on an object. I don't get why a for..in would work, but a for..of won't. Is it only for Arrays?

```
const config = { base: 'iei', url: 'www.' }

for (let i of config) { console.log(i); }
```

Comment: What would you expect it to log?

Comment: I would expect it to log 'iei' and 'www'

Comment: yeah looks like the same thing.. mine has a more explicit title though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `for of` is for [iterables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols). Not all objects are iterable. You can create a custom iterator for your object, though:

```
Object.values = function* (o) {
    for (let k of Object.keys(o))
        yield o[k];
};

for (let i of Object.values(config)) console.log(i); // 'iei', 'www.'
```